# push line strings to array of object

Tags: javascript

i want to push the data retreived into an array but it only push into the first object.

```
const arr = [{ name: 'name1', item: [] }, { name: 'name2', item: [] }];
routes.forEach((elementRoute) => {
  const { methods } = elementRoute;
  for (const m in methods) {
    let { title } = methods[m];
    arr[0].item.push({
      name: title,
      request: { method: m,},
    });
  }
});
```

my routes array is like this :

```
[
  {
    methods: {
      get: {
        title: 'get users',
      },
    },
  }
];
```

It only push into the first object of the item array.This is the result i actually want to get :

```
[
  {
    "name": "name1",
    "item": [
      { "name": "get users", "request": { "method": "get" } } }
    ]
  },
  {
    "name": "name2",
    "item": [
      { "name": "get users", "request": { "method": "get" } } }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: Your `routes` array is invalid: You placed commas after the last elements, like: `[{x:'something',},]`

Comment: it doesn't change anything in node.js

Comment: can you edit you question with what's your input and what do you want as an output ?

Comment: i just updated my question with what i get

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to iterate `arr` as well for getting all items filled.

```js
const 
    arr = [{ name: 'name1', item: [] }, { name: 'name2', item: [] }],
    routes = [{ methods: { get: { title: 'get users' } } }, { methods: { get: { title: 'get user id' }, delete: {} } }, ];

arr.forEach(({ item }) =>
    routes.forEach(({ methods }) => {
        for (const method in methods) {
            let { title: name = 'Not specified' } = methods[method];
            item.push({ name, request: { method } });
        }
    })
);

console.log(arr);
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Comment: i don't understand. please add what you have and wat you like to get.

Comment: it looks, you need a new question with an example, what you got. actually i can not distinguish, what you have and what is missing.

Comment: actually you make a new quetion in the old one. this makes any answer invalid. please ask a new question and highlight, what to do with the values of `iam`. and please roll back this question.